# Ignoring Apostrophes In Contains

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, contains

Simple question, perhaps a difficult answer.  We're using CONTAINS but when matching criteria containing apostrophes (because these are for French road names), then obviously they don't match.  So for example, searching for "Lislet" when the database contains "L'islet" yields nothing.

I've looked into using dictionaries and thesauruses (SQL features) but unfortunately neither do the job.  Thesauruses looked very promising, but upon testing in our environment, it became apparent that they don't support apostrophes, which is a big shame 'cause that would've worked perfectly.

The only other thing we're thinking of doing is creating a fully indexed view that strips out the apostrophes.

Any other bright ideas?

Comment: Have you already tried doing a string replace and using QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF?

Comment: My sentence "The only other thing we're thinking of doing is creating a fully indexed view that strips out the apostrophes" indicates towards this already.  You shouldn't strip out the apostrophes from the underlying table, because that's not an accurate representation of the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the Full-Text Catalog for your database?  There is an Accent sensitivity option.  You can select Sensitive or Insensitive.  I think you want this to be set to Insensitive, so that the apostrophes are ignored.

Comment: We've done that before directly in SQL, you can set it to LATIN_GENERAL_CI_AI, but that's something different.  Accent insensitive is for letters with accents on them, apostrophes != accents.